# Is it possible to get information of cache inside of GPU using perf event?

Tags: gpgpu, performancecounter, cpu-cache, perf, low-latency

I'm using perf event to get performance count or cache information (such as cache access count, cache miss count).
and now, I want to get GPU's cache information. But, the question is whether perf event can get GPU's cache information.
I did one test.

```
ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

matrixMulCUDA<<< grid, threads >>> ( ... );

ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);
```

and I confirmed data seem to be extracted.
But I can't be sure it's cache information inside of GPU.

Anybody knows about this??

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html (perf event tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

### <sub>A short version :</sub>  No.

---

### <sub>A longer version :</sub> Why this is not possible:

Your host operates one or two **`CPU`** processors <sub>( not speaking about respective `CPU`-cores thereof )</sub>, for which system tools alike **`perf`** can start and collect certain amount of "self-diagnostic telemetry" during the in-vivo operations, it is on the background, during the system work.

`perf` syntax supports all necessary parameters to specify ad-hoc which process / **`CPU`** to inspect and record data on-the-fly.

While this works fine as an ad-hoc observer for a **`CPU`**-hosted process, typical **`GPU`** operates many <sub>( read 14 or more )</sub>**`Streaming Multiprocessor`**-s, called **`SM`**, each equipped for about 16-32-64 parallel code-execution cores.

If this were the only obstacle, one can guess the host operating system may have some "spare" power to sniff it's few processes, but over-subscribing to this capability could easily destabilise a smooth operations remaing still "within the footprint" of that said "spare power".

Now imagine a hypothetical case, that a **`GPU`** were able to and would teleport and throw onto a poor solo / pair of your operating system `CPU`-resources a few hundred times larger ingress of such "performance telemetry" data and will let you to just close your eyes and rely on the same "spare power" of the hosting operating system to somehow chew it up.

**No, this would not be a fair move.** Not even trying to "swallow" a data-flow from a multi-**`GPU`** infrastructure ...

---

### Still, what if?

While there might be a need to do something wild in this direction, each `SM` has it's own set of **`L1`** / **`L2`** / **`texL`** cache resources and supposing a well designed **`TLP`**-architecture would allow for some "spare power"-in-**`GPU`** to be spent on `SM`-diagnostics overhead, you will have to code that yourself in a very wise manner, so as to limit the **`WARP-divergence`** side-effects on the GPU-kernel-code execution. While you can move some limited data through a pin-hole from `GPU`-code into host-address space via `DMA`/`RDMA`/`pinned-memory` alchemy, `GPU`-realm will not allow you to "read" telemetry data from `SM[13]` by a `SM[14]` et al.

---

### A good news is, that ...

for a sake of getting at least some insight or a raw view on how the `GPU`-hardware-architecture would let your specific `GPU`-kernel-code get aligned onto a specific `GPU`-hardware resources, the `GPU`-vendor provides a set of tools, one of which can elaborate a **simulated expectation** of the **`SM`** cache-usage / cache-spil-overs  <sub>( elaborated on your host operating system, during your specific `GPU`-kernel-code compilation into target `GPU`-hardware assembly language -- this could help you design / fine-tune / compiler-optimise the final `GPU`-kernel-code with respect to your priorities - minimise latency, maximise processing speed, keep highest `TLP` and `ILP` parallelism of `WARP`-code-executions )</sub>

---

### If still in doubts, ...

check how many on-chip **`JTAG`** diagnostic connectors do you get available from the **`GPU`**-fabric to connect to.

None...